# How can I print the country value from my JSON file in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I know that this could be an easy answer, but for me is difficult.  I have a Swift JSON file that loads successfully into my UserData variable.  But I want to get a value from that data set.  I get the error:  Value of type '[UserData]' has no member 'state'

```
[
  {
    "state":"Alaska",
    "latitude":61.3850,
    "longitude":-152.2683,
    "stateTax":"7%"
  },
  {
    "state":"Alabama",
    "latitude":32.7990,
    "longitude":-86.8073,
    "stateTax":"13.5%"
  },
  {
    "state":"Arkansas",
    "latitude":34.9513,
    "longitude":-92.3809,
    "stateTax":"11.625%"
  }
]
```

My data set UserData:

```
[LoadFromJSON.UserData(state: "Alaska", latitude: 61.385, longitude: -152.2683, stateTax: "7%"), LoadFromJSON.UserData(state: "Alabama", latitude: 32.799, longitude: -86.8073, stateTax: "13.5%"), LoadFromJSON.UserData(state: "Arkansas", latitude: 34.9513, longitude: -92.3809, stateTax: "11.625%")]
```

My code and the error line:

```
 do {
                let data =  try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([UserData].self, from: data)
                
                self.userData = dataFromJson
                
                print(userData)
                print(dataFromJson.state)  // Value of type '[UserData]' has no member 'state'
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```

Comment: `dataFromJson` is an array of `UserData`, if you want to print out the `state` you need to get a specific instance from the array (e.g. `dataFromJson.first?.state`)

Comment: @shim it will only print for first user.

Comment: That is just an example, OP gave no indication of what he was trying to do

Comment: You are right, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataFromJson` is array of `UserData`, so you need to iterate like this.

```swift
do {
                let data =  try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([UserData].self, from: data)
                
                self.userData = dataFromJson
                dataFromJson.forEach{ user in

                    print(user.state)

                }
                
                print(userData)
                
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```